# iPhone OS: Using an NSString variable to specify a property or ivar

Tags: iphone, variables, syntax, nsstring

I have a program that I want to either hide or show certain UIbuttons depending on certain variables and all the buttons are named incrementally like 'button1, button2, button3.'

So I want to iterate through the buttons but I don't know how to address the button in an assignment statement using an nsstring as a variable inside a dot notation assignment, such as:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < weekday; i++) {
    int buttonIncrement = 0;
    NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
    @"calbutton%i", buttonIncrement];

 self.tempString.hidden = YES;
}
```

The "tempString" part of the assignment I want to tell it to insert "calbuttonx" where x is the button number.

Can you do this somehow? if so please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also assign a tag to each button in IB and get the button associated with the tag using

```
- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag
```

as defined on class [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:), for example:

```
for( int k = 0; k < 5; ++k ) {

    id subview = [self.view viewWithTag: k];

    if( subview ) { 

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome i think this will work, ill let you know of the progress as I'm sure you can't waitto find out, lol.

Thanks again!

Comment: yes this definitely worked, although I am ending up having to rework the code anyway into a more programatic approach but I really do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array!

---

If you can't use an array, you can reference to a property by string with [Key-Value Coding (KVC)](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1):

```
UIButton* button = [self valueForKey:tempString];
button.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: I was trying to use interface builder for the buttons because that is what I know, any way to use IB with the array or do you then have to layout the interface programatically?

Comment: @nick: I think the array needs to be populated programmatically.